# I want to call alert view first then go to further NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to call alert view first then go to NSManagedObject. But when i click on button then it skip alert view and call this at the end of rest code.

Any one know's how can i force this uialertview to load first

Thanks

```
- (IBAction)confirmOrder:(UIButton *)sender
{

#pragma PopUp Alert Box
    _alert = [MLTableAlert tableAlertWithTitle:@"Select Your Table" cancelButtonTitle:nil numberOfRows:^NSInteger (NSInteger section)
                  {
                      return 6;
                  }
                                          andCells:^UITableViewCell* (MLTableAlert *anAlert, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
                  {
                      static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
                      UITableViewCell *cell = [anAlert.table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
                      if (cell == nil)
                          cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

                      cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Table # %d", indexPath.row];

                      return cell;
                  }];

    [_alert configureSelectionBlock:^(NSIndexPath *selectedIndex){

        NSLog(@"Index is = %d", selectedIndex.row);
        selectedTable = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",selectedIndex.row];
#pragma Hit Url For New Order

        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        NSLog(@"Got udid from appdelegate = %@",appDelegate.passUdid);
        NSString *new_order = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://localhost/food/submit_new_order.php?id=NULL&customer_id=%@&table_id=%@&order_datetime=%@&customer_instruction=Normal&estimated_time_min=30-45&actual_time=40&created_on=%@&updated_on=NULL&STATUS=new", appDelegate.passUdid,selectedTable,dateStr,dateStr];
        NSString* urlTextEscaped = [new_order stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlTextEscaped];
        NSData *myNSData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    } andCompletionBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"Cancel Button Pressed\nNo Cells Selected");
    }];
    _alert.height = 260;
    [_alert show];

   NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSError *error=nil;
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"PendingOrder" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];


    //e
    if (![selectedTable isEqualToString:NULL]) {

    for (NSManagedObject *info in fetchedObjects) {
        NSMutableString *pDishID = [info valueForKey:@"dishid"];
        NSMutableString *pDishQuantity = [info valueForKey:@"quantity"];
        NSMutableString *time = [info valueForKey:@"time"];
        NSManagedObject *newDevices = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"RunningOrder" inManagedObjectContext:context];
         [newDevices setValue:pDishID forKey:@"dishid"];
         [newDevices setValue:pDishQuantity forKey:@"quantity"];
        [newDevices setValue:time forKey:@"time"];

        NSLog(@"Getting ID From pending Order = %@",[info valueForKey:@"dishid"]);
#pragma Get Order ID from Order_Main
        //s
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        NSString *ordrMain=@"http://localhost/food/get_order_id.php?id=";
        ordrMain = [ordrMain stringByAppendingString:appDelegate.passUdid];
        NSURL *urls=[NSURL URLWithString:ordrMain];
        NSData *myNSData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urls];

        allItemss = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myNSData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        NSDictionary *results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myNSData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
        NSString *get_order_id = [[allItemss objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"id"];
        NSString *new_order_detail = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://localhost/food/order_detail.php?order_id=%@&dish_id=%@&quantity=%@&created_on=%@&updated_on=%@", get_order_id,pDishID,pDishQuantity,dateStr,dateStr];
        NSString* urlTextEscaped = [new_order_detail stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlTextEscaped];
        NSData *myNSDatas=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        [context deleteObject:info];

    }
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[_alert show]` displays the alert window and returns immediately. The "selection block"
is then called when an alert item has been pressed, or the "cancel block" is called
when the Cancel button has been pressed.

Therefore you have to move the code that fetches the managed object into the "selection block":

```
[_alert configureSelectionBlock:^(NSIndexPath *selectedIndex){
    NSLog(@"Index is = %d", selectedIndex.row);
    // ...
    // Fetch object depending on selectedIndex.
    // ...
} andCompletionBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"Cancel Button Pressed\nNo Cells Selected");
}];
```

Comment: Cool idea. Let me try this

Comment: Perfect. Thanks alooot man. I was wondering from last4 hour's